# Open CL speedup obtained is above 7000

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I have an OpenCL sequential program and a parallel program which consists of the same algorithm. I have got the execution time results as 133000 milliseconds for sequential and 17 milliseconds as the kernel time for parallel. So when I calculate the speed up that is 133000/17 i get 7823 as the speedup. Whether this much of speed up possible?

Comment: What exactly is your program doing? Show some code (e.g. an [MCVE]) in your question, so please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: That's really big... Did you carefully compare the two output to see if the job if properly done?

Comment: Also explain in your question how you compiled your code. Without a lot more details (some code, the compilation commands, the benchmarking protocol, the actual hardware and compiler) your question is too broad. Please **improve your question**

Comment: You have a simple loop in kernel? That is not pipelined then. But millions of kernels get pipelined.

Comment: Are you sure you benchmarked the OpenCL side correctly? You can't just measure the time to execute the clEnqueueNDRangeWorkItems since it is just queueing up work. You must have a blocking read or clFinish included in your benchmarking to include all of the transfer and compute. Alternatively, you can take a cl_event on the kernel and ask it how long it took.

Answer (score 0):

Such a speedup might happen (but seems quite big; to me, a speedup of 7823 looks *suspicious* but not entirely impossible, see e.g. [these slides](https://www.karlrupp.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/PHSP2014-tutorial.pdf) and [that](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~cavazos/cisc879/Lecture-06.pdf). A 100x factor would seem more reasonable). Costly graphics cards are rumored to be able to run at several teraflops. A single core gives only gigaflops. Some particular programs can even run slower on GPGPU than on the CPU.

When benchmarking your CPU code, be sure to enable optimizations in your compiler (e.g. compile with `gcc -O2` at least with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Without any optimization (e.g. `gcc -O0`) the CPU performance is slow (e.g. a 3x factor between binary obtained with `gcc -O0` and `gcc -O2` is common).

BTW, [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) considerations matter a lot for CPU performance. If you wrote your numerical CPU code without taking that into account, it may be quite slow (in the weird case when it has bad [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)).

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel function has a problem and has not been executed, the time results will be inaccurate